# How do I determine the velocity I need to cover the same distance if I'm moving at an angle

Tags: trigonometry

I'm not sure how to word this problem exactly.

If I know I cover 100 meters every second if I'm travelling at 100 meters per second when travelling across a flat plane. How can I determine how much distance, according to that flat plane, I cover if I'm travelling at an angle away from the plane? And what would my new velocity need to be to cover the same 100 meters?

Here's a picture:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

100 meters per sec divided by $\cos \,a
.$

Answer (score 0):

To find the length of the hypotenuse (angled away line) think sohcahtoa, then calculte the velocity to travel the new distance within the same time.